# Openapi operationid is repeated

Tags: java, maven, openapi

I'm using Open-API to generate java class using yaml file. when i run

> mvn clean install

i'm getting this error :

```
unexpected error in Open-API generation
org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException: There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
 | Error count: 3, Warning count: 6
Errors: 
    -attribute paths.'/path/{id}'(delete).operationId is repeated
    -attribute paths.'/path/name'(get).operationId is repeated
```

How can i skeep this validation ?

Comment: It says right there in the error message: _"The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI)."_ Have you tried this?

Comment: @Helen i'm not able to find this option in the pom file. not sure where to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

Within your POM.xml -> Plugin -> Find openAPI generation plug-in -> configuration -> configOptions ->

```
<validateSpec>false</validateSpec>
```

This should work hopefully ! :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the correct place of `validateSpec` was `configuration` instead of `configOptions`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>abc-api</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                ...
                <validateSpec>false</validateSpec>
                <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                <configOptions>
                    <developerOrganization>ABC</developerOrganization>
                    ...
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Note**: I have to add both `validateSpec` and `skipValidateSpec` for version 6.2.1 as per suggestion in an open bug https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9815

Answer (score 1):

Try to add syntax "schema": {"type": "string"} to *.Json file.

I aslo got the error with respose like that:

There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
| Error count: 12, Warning count: 20
Errors:
-attribute paths.'/.../items'(get).responses.304.ETag.type is unexpected
-attribute paths.'/.../items'(get).responses.304.Last-Modified.type is unexpected
-attribute paths.'/.../items'(get).responses.200.ETag.type is unexpected

This is my fix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Cd2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLKg0.png)

```
"headers": {
                        "ETag": {
                            "description": "Used as caching key for future requests.",
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "example": "33a64df551425fcc55e4d42a1466666666666666666"
                            }
                        },
                        "Cache-Control": {
                            "description": "The Cache-Control header.",
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "example": "max-age=1000000"
                            }
                        },
                        "Last-Modified":  {
                            "description": "The last modified the response.",
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "example": "Sun, 11 Nov 2021 15:30:51 ICT"
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I hope this one can help you. You cant read more document with response header here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/