# Configuring Spring Boot REST API project with yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, yaml, microservices

It is my first time working with Spring Boot REST API. I would like to build a Spring Boot Project with 2 microservices: UserManagement and Messaging.

I have the following yaml file  for my UserManagement API endpoint:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: UMS Service
  version: 1.0.0
  title: UMS API
host: ums
basePath: /api/v1
tags:
  - name: role
    description: Operations about roles
  - name: user
    description: Operations about users
  - name: login/logout
    description: Operations about sessions
schemes:
  - https
  - http
paths:
  /role:
    post:
      tags:
        - role
      summary: Create role
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: createRole
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Created role object
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Role'
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
    get:
      tags:
        - role
      summary: Get role by name
      description: ''
      operationId: getRoleByName
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: rolename
          in: query
          description: The name that needs to be fetched.
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Role'
        '400':
          description: Invalid rolename supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: Role not found
    put:
      tags:
        - role
      summary: Updated role name
      operationId: updateRole
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: rolename
          in: query
          description: name that need to be updated
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Updated role object
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Role'
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid role supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: Role not found
    delete:
      tags:
        - role
      summary: Delete role
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: deleteRole
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: rolename
          in: query
          description: The role that needs to be deleted
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid role supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: Role not found
  /user:
    post:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Create user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: createUser
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Created user object
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
    get:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Get user by user name
      description: ''
      operationId: getUserByName
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          description: The name that needs to be fetched
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
        '400':
          description: Invalid username supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: User not found
    put:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Updated user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: updateUser
      produces:
        - application/xml
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Updated user object
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid user supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: User not found
    delete:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Delete user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: deleteUser
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          description: The name that needs to be deleted
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid username supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: User not found
  /user/role:
    post:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Assign role to user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: createUserRole
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Created user object
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserRole'
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
    get:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Get role by user name
      description: ''
      operationId: getRoleByUserName
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          description: The name that needs to be fetched
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserRole'
        '400':
          description: Invalid username supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: User not found
    put:
      tags:
        - user
      summary: Updated user's role
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: updateUserRole
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Updated user object with new role
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UserRole'
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid username supplied
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
        '404':
          description: User not found
  /session/login:
    get:
      tags:
        - login/logout
      summary: Get last login for user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: getLastSessionStart
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Session'
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
  /session/logout:
    get:
      tags:
        - login/logout
      summary: Get last logout for user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: getLastSessionEnd
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Session'
        '401':
          description: Not authenticated
    post:
      tags:
        - login/logout
      summary: Set logout for user
      description: This can only be done by the logged in user.
      operationId: setLastSessionEnd
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: Set Log out data for user
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Session'
      responses:
        default:
          description: successful operation
securityDefinitions:
  ums_auth:
    type: oauth2
    authorizationUrl: 'http://ums/oauth/user'
    flow: implicit
    scopes:
      'write:users': modify users in your account
      'read:users': read user data
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: api_key
    in: header
definitions:
  UserRole:
    type: object
    properties:
       username:
         type: string
       rolename:
         type: string
  Role:
    type: object
    properties:
      rolename:
        type: string
  User:
    type: object
    properties:
      username:
        type: string
      email:
        type: string
      password:
        type: string
      role:
        type: string
  Session:
    type: object
    properties:
      username:
        type: string
      login:
        type: number
      logout:
        type: number
```

My question is: how do I configure my UserManagement Service to communicate with this yaml file and generate its contents in a web browser? I am using Eclipse with STS3 plugin.

Thank you for any suggestions. Also, I'd be grateful to sample links to Spring Boot REST API projects with application.yml files which could help me build a simple Spring Boot REST API with 2 services.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to read your YML file and generate an OAS (Open API specification) out of it.

**Not completely tried from scratch, but check if below helps**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/oas/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
          <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
          <modelPackage>com.xyz....</modelPackage>
          <apiPackage>com.xyz...</apiPackage>
          <output>./../api</output>
          <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
          <configOptions>
            <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
            <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
          </configOptions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

**You may reach out to the one who asked a similar question on this article, he might have tried from scratch** [Openapi operationid is repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529163/openapi-operationid-is-repeated/70530471#70530471)